# What is the correlation method used in the ccf() function in R?

Tags: r, correlation, cross-correlation

I am trying to find out what method of correlation (e.g., spearman, pearson, kendall) is used in the cross-correlation function `ccf()` in R. Does anyone know the answer?

I compared two time series using `cor(x=x,y=y, method='spearman')` and also compared them using `ccf(x=x,y=y)`. While the spearman correlation was significant, no lags were significant in the `ccf()`. I am trying to understand how the 2 methods are producing different results

Answer (score 0):

I just found this [StackExchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209839/cross-correlation-with-spearmans-method) post that says the cross-correlation in R uses the Pearson method by default.

Comment: add an example to prove it